# How know directly which signal wakes up a computer?

Tags: hibernate, window, wake-up

I am turning my Windows 8 box into hibernate for night. But at morning I am finding it wake up. I know I can use trial and error method to find what is turning it on. But is there any registry, which remembers wake up signal, which woke up a computer this time?

Comment: This question provides some tips: [How do I prevent Windows 7 laptop from waking up automatically?](http://superuser.com/a/304940/289138)

Comment: You might also want to [disable wake timers](http://www.howtogeek.com/122954/how-to-prevent-your-computer-from-waking-up-accidentally/) to prevent scheduled tasks from waking up your computer. To see if you have any wake timers enabled on your system, use the command `powercfg -waketimers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a command prompt and run `powercfg -lastwake`.

You can do this in a batch file like this:

lastwake.bat (put it on your desktop for easy access)

```
powercfg -lastwake
pause
```

At the `Wake Source` it should state your wake-up source.

Comment: I didn't know you about this command. I just tried it out and it works well. For anyone who gets `Wake History Count - 0` as the output of this command, it's because your computer hasn't woken up from sleep yet (e.g. reboot, powered up after a shutdown, etc.)