# Why is TeamViewer setting up a wake timer in the middle of the night and how to disable it?

Tags: windows-10, power-management, teamviewer, wake-up

After upgrading to Windows 10, my PC started waking up at the middle of the night. I have run all the routine checks and made sure that no hardware has the option enabled. However, upon running `powercfg /waketimers`, I get the following

```
Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume5\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer_Service.exe (TeamViewer) expires at 00:49:35 on 12.08.15.
Reason: generic
```

I skimmed through the preferences on TeamViewer and  could not find a way to disable it. Why is TeamViewer setting up such a timer, and how to disable it without uninstalling or deactivating the software?

Comment: Did you check your [task scheduler](http://superuser.com/a/304941/270195) for **TeamViewer** ? Remove it if it is there.

Comment: This is a [known issue](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2744717/teamviewer-computer-randomly-wake-sleep.html) with Windows 10. People in the thread said updating fixed it for them.