# How to Delete Waketimers set by a program

Tags: windows-7, vpn

On my work computer, we use Cisco AnyConnect (Windows 7).  It keeps waking up my computer.

Running `powercfg -waketimers` gives a list of waketimers, all by the VPN client, for example:

```
Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\acwebsecagent.exe (acwebsecagent) expires at 5:29:06 AM on 2/28/2017.
  Reason: generic
```

These timers are not listed anywhere in the windows task scheduler and I don't know how to get rid of them, and IT just keeps trying to uninstall/reinstall which is not working.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem with acwebsecagent in company laptop. Under some uncertain conditions (not always!) it keeps waking up the computer 2 minutes after hibernation.

As it is application set wake timer, and AnyConnect doesn't seem to allow changing it in its setting, I'd say we cannot disable the timer. Nonetheless I was able to make it ignored by disabling wake timers in power scheme advanced options (weirdly in my case it was enabled when on battery, but not on AC).

See screenshot in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/304935/how-do-i-prevent-windows-7-laptop-from-waking-up-automatically).

Still, I'm not sure whether it can be overriden somehow, e.g. by GPO. Then I'd create a scheduled task to do it for me using powercfg command.